# Java Selenium Chromedriver loads Cookies but does not use them

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

i need to access a website multiple times a day and want to skip the Log-In page. This is why i want to use Cookies in Java Selenium Chromedriver, for skipping that Log-In after accessing it the first time on a day.
Selenium is saving the Cookies correctly, but does not use them and i dont get access on the following page. Can you help me?

This is my Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Set<Cookie> cookie = null;
    Iterator<Cookie> itr = null;
    while (true) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Maxi\\Desktop\\ChromeDriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.xxxxxx.xxx");

        while (itr != null && itr.hasNext()) {
            driver.manage().addCookie(itr.next());
        }

        driver.navigate().refresh();

        WebDriverWait wait0 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        if (itr == null) {
            String UserID = "LoginFieldXpath";
            wait0.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(UserID)));

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(UserID)).sendKeys("Username");

            String PW = "PasswordField Xpath";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(PW)).sendKeys("Password");

            String LogIn = "LoginButtonXpath";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(LogIn)).click();

            cookie = driver.manage().getCookies();
            itr = cookie.iterator();    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create user profile in Chrome like this 
options:

```
addArguments("user-data-dir="+"path_to_empty_folder");
```

Then make sign up, so cookie will be stored in this profile. And than just copy this user data dir to another folder

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("path-to-dir-with-cookie"), new File("new-dir"));
options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+"new-dir");
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium starts a new temporary browser instance each time, so it doesn't come with any cookies stored, cache or anything like that.

I would suggest moving your open chrome driver to be outside of the while loop so you'll be able to reuse it each time you want to check a page. Maybe either move the login outside of the loop as well or check if you need to log in. Then just grab whatever page you're trying to check inside the loop each time you need to.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Set<Cookie> cookie = null;
    Iterator<Cookie> itr = null;

    // move this outside the loop
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Maxi\\Desktop\\ChromeDriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    while (true) {

        driver.get("https://www.xxxxxx.xxx");

        // not sure why you're adding a cookie?
        // it should automatically accept page cookies that are set
        while (itr != null && itr.hasNext()) {
            driver.manage().addCookie(itr.next());
        }

        driver.navigate().refresh();

        WebDriverWait wait0 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

        // check to make sure that you need to log in
        if (itr == null) {
            String UserID = "LoginFieldXpath";
            wait0.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(UserID)));

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(UserID)).sendKeys("Username");

            String PW = "PasswordField Xpath";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(PW)).sendKeys("Password");

            String LogIn = "LoginButtonXpath";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(LogIn)).click();

            cookie = driver.manage().getCookies();
            itr = cookie.iterator();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

In the future I want to create an executable jar with this code, without the while loop.
The jar should be start every minute by a linux script. 
To safe time and traffic I want to store the cookies in a text file. 
If the jar starts a second time I want to read out the text file and insert the cookies, so I don't have to login again.
The problem is, that the inserted cookies have currently no influence and I get the login page every time.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Is there a reason to store this in a text file? Seems a database would be a better choice. Anyway, are you sure that the cookie is being set right with all the correct data?